# Unable to integrate Google Cloud Messaging in an android library module

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I am able to integrate GCM in an application module but unable to integrate in library module.I have these two lines in the app module.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have this line of code in dependencies of app module.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
```

and this line is in projects top level

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'
```

But when I am trying to implement a service by extending GcmListenerService, it is unable to detect GcmListenerService.

Please give suggestions, I am trying for more than 5 hours but unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: Simply include `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'` in your app gradle file. nothing else

Comment: I have already added the code which you are talking about, but no result.

Comment: remove any dependency you have added

Comment: did you follow this https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/messaging/add_module and read this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints

Comment: I want to receive the push notification not want send

Comment: Was GcmListenerService being detected before used it in your library module?

Comment: yes it is detected when i compiled it with plugin "com.android.application"

Answer (score 0):

First you have add gcm jar into your project by adding following code into app gradle file

```
ependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
}
```

then synch the project

Comment: We don't need gcm.jar anymore .